# loading Image in RecyclerView Adapter using volley

Tags: android, android-volley, android-recyclerview, image-loading

I am facing an issue similar to the one in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36610771/android-loading-image-with-volley-recyclerview) post. I am using volley library to load only images into my  (horizontal) recyclerview adapter. But I get a runtime exception every time I swipe the view to the left or right.
I can use picasso but i want to know what the real problem is!

**Logcat**

```
 E/Volley: [187] NetworkDispatcher.run: Unhandled exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:829)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:808)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:739)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:615)
at com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageRequest.doParse(ImageRequest.java:202)
at com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageRequest.parseNetworkResponse(ImageRequest.java:159)
at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:123)
```

I have implemented singletonRequestQueue as mentioned in the [android documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/requestqueue.html).

**the image loading code snippet in recyclerAdapter**

```
imageLoader = SingletonRequestQueue.getInstance(mContext).getImageLoader();
        String URL = Images.get(position);
        holder.itemImage.setImageUrl(URL, imageLoader);
```

Any help would be appriciated.
Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17605662/illegalargumentexception-width-and-height-must-be-0-while-loading-bitmap-from

Comment: What version of volley are you using? I've checked the source code. The line number doesn't match.

Comment: 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'